# Unable to re-subscribe to subject after unsubscribing

Tags: angular, typescript, socket.io, rxjs, behaviorsubject

When I change the route and come back to the same route where the subject was subscribed, it creates a duplicate listener every time I change the route.

To stop this, I used the unsubscribed functionality of subjects, but the problem came after unsubscribing the subject. I'm unable to subscribe it again and not able to listen to the event.

`socketservices.ts`:

```
connect(): Rx.BehaviorSubject<MessageEvent> {
// We define our observable which will observe any incoming messages
// from our socket.io server.
let observable = new Observable(observer => {
  this.socket.on('message', (data) => {
    observer.next(data);
  })
  return () => {
    this.socket.disconnect();
  }
});

// We define our Observer which will listen to messages
// from our other components and send messages back to our
// socket server whenever the `next()` method is called.
let observer = {
  next: (data: Object) => {
    console.log('sending message')
    this.socket.emit('message', JSON.stringify(data));
  },
};

// we return our Rx.Subject which is a combination
// of both an observer and observable.
return Rx.BehaviorSubject.create(observer, observable);
}
```

`admincomponent.ts`:

```
//constructor includes public webSoc:SocketServiceService
this.subscription = this.webSoc.connect().subscribe(data=>{
  if (data['response'] == "dvc_board") {
    console.log('listening')
    this._updatebins()
  }
})
```

Comment: Okay, so when or where do you unsubscribe? You left the most important part out, I guess. Please, add the missing piece of code.